# error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, jenkins, nuget, nuget-package

I am observing this below error when I build my Jenkins Job.

[image]

Error clearly says that it is missing file `D:\Services.Package.Search\src\packages\Grpc.Core.1.0.1\build\net45\Grpc.Core.targets` 
But my workspace location is different. Why its not referring to this path `"C:\PackageSearch\BTP\src\packages\Grpc.Core.1.0.1\build\net45"` . Is anything I need to change in csproj file.

[image]

```
Error :
```

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   D:\Services.Package.Search\src\packages\Grpc.Core.1.0.1\build\net45\Grpc.Core.targets.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909506/this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the absolute path may be written in your csproj file. Try changing it to a relative path that references the targets file.

Packages are downloaded to *\packages* by default. The path in the error appears to be outside of that.