# Nuget installed panel empty after VS 2017 update

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I updated my VS to 15.7.3 version today and now my Nuget panel with installed packages is empty. Not empty but showing only System.Runtime.

I have a packages.config file in my project and everything worked just fine before the update.

Also the solution wont build. It is showing the following error

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.1.0.21\build\Microsoft.Bcl.Build.targets. C:\Users\User\Source\Repos\xxxx1-sol\xxxx1\xxxx1.csproj 6039
```

What might be the problem ?

Update 1

I tried installing all of the packages again and after I installed a couple of them I saw this in References

[image: References window]

Update 2:

I tried deleting the .packages folder before installing the packages again via Nuget and the folder .packages was not created

My project path is C:\Users\User\Source\Repos\Project123-Git

Also I see that now I have a folder .nuget at C:\Users\User.nuget that has the folder packages in it.

I also tried deleting the file packages.config but Nuget still has my newly installed packages even if packages.config does not exsist

Comment: Check this SO link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909506/this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer

Comment: It did not help :(

Comment: Does your `packages.config` still contain a list of those packages now? If yes, please try to delete the target `<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    ...
  </Target>` in your project file .csproj, then execute the command "update-package -reinstall" in the Package Manager Console window.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Yes, all my packages are still in packages.confing but deleting the "EnsureNuGet..." did not change anything :( - the Nuget installed panel is still empty

Comment: Imho your NuGet Package Manager is not up to date. Go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Visual Studio Gallery and check what version you have there.

Comment: @Peska I dont have Visual Studio Gallery in Extensions and Updates

Comment: Click Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio. Then find NuGet Package Manager there. What is your version?

Comment: @Peska Version 4.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a suggestion on Github Nuget page I managed to find a solution

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7013

I unloaded the project, opened the project file and removed all the PackageReference nodes from it. I then deleted the obj folder and Nuget started recognizing my packages again. Project now builds just fine.

Thank you all for your help