# ASP.NET issue - Nuget Packages are missing

Tags: asp.net

I tried to run an ASP.NET project but got this error. It's not my own code and I got it from someone.

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package 
Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105
```

I checked this

> [This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909506/this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer)

But it was not the solution. I just removed something regarding that but it's not perfect. I want to know the correct reason why this error appears. And if some packages were missed, how can I restore correctly. I enabled auto Nuget restore(`Tools/Options/Nuget Package Manager/Package Restore`) but it didn't work.

Another thing is:
I checked the source and it doesn't include .nuget folder. But there is .nuget folder in Visual Studio Solution Explore. If I click .nuget/NuGet.ext, then it alerts "It has been renames, deleted or removed".
I have no idea about this. Why do this folder and files created in VS even though they don't appear on pc explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this the other day when pulling in a commit from our team's repo. Our solution was to unload the project and to change the project properties to include the actual reference off the dll (We have a shared network folder that stores all of our dlls) It might not be the perfect solution, but it works for us.