# How to kill VBCSCompiler.exe on Ubuntu agent?

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines

I created an Azure Devops Build pipeline and i am trying to build my ASP.NET MVC and Angular hybrid site project on bitbucket (git).

The project first gets checked out, and nuget restores the necessary packages, and then the .NET builds. I used windows 2019 as azure pipeline agent for the build to succeed. however, Its taking about 7 minutes to complete, whilst running the tasks (besides .Net) on a ubuntu agent is much faster! takes around 2 mins instead!

Therefore, I'd like to use ubuntu, but im running into an issue with the MSBuild task...

```
"/home/vsts/work/1/s/Bobby.ProjectA/Bobby.ProjectA.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(KillVBCSCompilerAndRetryCopy target) -> 
/home/vsts/work/1/s/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8/build/net45/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(23,5): 
error MSB4044: The "KillProcess" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ImagePath". [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Bobby.ProjectA/Bobby.ProjectA.csproj]
```

According to [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71302/binroslyn-files-locked-during-build.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=votes&type=problem), `VBCSCompiler.exe` continues running from the Compiler Nuget package (nuget restore task?) so it locks the src folders and prevented future builds from running, e.g. causing error like this:

```
/home/vsts/work/1/s/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8/build/net45/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props(17,5): 
warning MSB3021: Unable to copy file "/home/vsts/work/1/s/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0/build/../tools/csc.exe" to "/bin/roslyn/csc.exe". Access to the path '/bin/roslyn' is denied. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Bobby.ProjectA/Bobby.ProjectA.csproj]
```

So the solution would be to kill the `VBCSCompiler.exe` but since i cant actually access the hosted machine during the build, im not sure how to do that.

screenshot of my pipeline so far:

[image: pipeline]

Am i facing a dead-end path here with this approach? The build runs fine on windows 2019 but it just takes too long, so thats why if i can make it run on ubuntu successfully that would be great!

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? How did it go?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT none of the options worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build on Ubuntu 20 finally worked! I don't know why removing these lines resolved the VBCSCompiler issue, but by doing so, the msbuild completed successfully on Ubunutu 20 agent!!

Remove the following lines from the `.csproj` file:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />

<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
```

To give some context to the answer, this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23852183/8397835) indicated that converting from MSBuild-Integrated Package Restore to Automatic Package Restore (nuget restore task) implied that the `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` `<Import>` and `<Error Condition>` snippets are no longer relevant/needed in the `.csproj` file.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT The build on Ubuntu 20 finally worked! Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with below workarounds:

1,Set MSBUILD arguements `/p:UseSharedCompilation=false`.

You can add above arguement to the msbuild arguements field of the msbuild task. See [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71302/binroslyn-files-locked-during-build.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=votes&type=problem).

[image]

2,Upgrade Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform nupkg to the latest and remove Microsoft.Net.Compilers nupkg from your project. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider#version-200) for more information.

3, Try Specifing the TTL of Roslyn compiler server.

You can define a pipeline variable `VBCSCOMPILER_TTL` on the Variable tab to specify a shorter idle time for `VBCSCompiler.exe`

Or you can add `<providerOption name="CompilerServerTimeToLive" value="[num of seconds]" />` under `system.codedom/compilers/compiler` in the config file. See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider#run-time-options) for more information.

4, Use `CheckIfShouldKillVBCSCompiler` target:

You can try add below to your csproj file:

```
<Target Name="CheckIfShouldKillVBCSCompiler">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ShouldKillVBCSCompiler>true</ShouldKillVBCSCompiler>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/57#issuecomment-408428373).

Comment: Levi, how do i nest the Target (option 4) in the before build target? please find my post here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65308692/how-to-nest-a-target-within-another-target-in-the-csproj-file

Comment: @Cataster  You can try using [BeforeTargets attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2019#example-aftertargets-and-beforetargets). eg. `<Target Name="CheckIfShouldKillVBCSCompiler" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">`. or setting the [InitialTargets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-specify-which-target-to-build-first?view=vs-2019) eg.`<Project InitialTargets="CheckIfShouldKillVBCSCompiler">`.

Comment: The BeforeBuild targets didnt work. I also tried `BeforeTargets="Build"` and that didnt work either. I also tried putting the property group inside the BeforeBuid Target itself but that didnt work either. I want to attempt the inititialtargets you proposed, but where do i add it? There is only 1 project element and it already has a default target...is it ok to override it? or do i just have to include it along with it like this: `<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" InitialTargets="CheckIfShouldKillVBCSCompiler" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

Comment: its not working either way. i have one last option: restarting the build agent before the MSBuild task, but idk what task to add/how to restart the ubuntu agent on the pipeline...

Comment: @Cataster You cannot restart the agent during the pipeline execution. You can try adding a bash task before MSbuild task to kill the VBCSCompiler.exe process. `killall VBCSCompiler`. see [here](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-find-the-process-id-of-a-program-and-kill-it-quick-tip/)

Comment: i got this error: `VBCSCompiler: no process found`

Comment: I am stuck right now. If the VBCSCompiler process is not really running, then why `Access to the path '/bin/roslyn' is denied.`? this post here makes it sounds like its definitely a VBCSCompiler issue, which is why i have been attempting all these options for so long now. but if this whole time this isnt really the issue the access is denied, then what could possibly be the issue? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71302/binroslyn-files-locked-during-build.html?page=2&pageSize=10&sort=votes&type=problem