# How to restart ubuntu agent on Azure Build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Long story short, after trying out several solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65283319/8397835) to kill the VBCSCompiler before the MSBuild task didnt work out, I am gonna try one more option before calling it a day and just having to stick to windows2019 agent, even though the build time will be tripled.

So, after NuGet restore task, i need to reboot the ubuntu agent (hosted by Azure Pipelines Agent pool), i added a command-line task, but i am not sure what to write for the script...

I tried the following script command `sudo reboot`

but it didn't work (kept running for a while so i just cancelled the build)

[image: long]

I've also tried this command instead:

```
init 6
```

but I got an error:

```
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to reboot system via logind: Interactive authentication required.
Failed to open initctl fifo: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible, when you restart your Hosted Agent your build will fail. this is reason why is not allowed.