# Project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, build, nuget-package

This morning I received the following error when trying to build my Visual Studio ASP.NET solution:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
> computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
> information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
> missing file is
> ..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props.

I performed a NuGet Package Restore as instructed but the results stated that: all packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.

The NuGet Package Manager settings are as follows:

[NuGet Package Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttSI3.jpg)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is this related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909506/this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer ?

Comment: I looked at that item and I found that I could not edit the .csproj file in Visual Studio as the 'Unload Project' item is greyed out.

Comment: Please uninstall the Package System.CodeDom and reinstall else you can remove the reference and delete CodeDom section from web config it'll help you

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Sorry, I'm a bit of a novice, can you explain to me how I could do this?