# ERROR :This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package, nuget, project

I can't run the project because of this error:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
> computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
> information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
> missing file is
> packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props.

Comment: Maybe this question and its answers can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909506/642579

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/Consume-Packages/Package-restore-troubleshooting#this-project-references-nuget-packages-that-are-missing-on-this-computer) for package restore using the method mentioned there. It's best to clear all nuget caches under Tools>Options>NuGet Package Manager>General before doing this.